# Rosdep Import error

Tags: ros, python, rosdep, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install a ros package on ubuntu 16.04 and ros kinetic version. However, the rosdep init seems to give following error:

```
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosdep", line 3, in 
    from rosdep2.main import rosdep_main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/__init__.py", line 45, in 
    from .lookup import RosdepDefinition, RosdepView, RosdepLookup, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 44, in 
    from .sources_list import SourcesListLoader
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 49, in 
    from .gbpdistro_support import get_gbprepo_as_rosdep_data, download_gbpdistro_as_rosdep_data
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/gbpdistro_support.py", line 18, in 
    from .platforms.debian import APT_INSTALLER
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/debian.py", line 34, in 
    from rospkg.os_detect import OS_DEBIAN, OS_LINARO, OS_UBUNTU, OS_ELEMENTARY, OS_MX, OsDetect, read_os_release
ImportError: cannot import name OS_MX
```

This seems some python issue, but I have tried reinstalling: rosdep, ros kinetic, python and even did a reset of bashrc. If I remove the OS_MX, some OS_EMBEDDDED gives import error.

Rospkg version is 1.1.9

What could be the case here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324349/rosdep-import-error/) by [elementaryshr](https://answers.ros.org/users/41127/elementaryshr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-30**:
A guess, but seeing as you're on Ubuntu 14.04: it could be that `rospkg` is not up-to-date enough on your system. Causing `rosdep` to fail when it tries to import symbols that should be part of `rospkg` but aren't on your system.

**Comment by [elementaryshr](https://answers.ros.org/users/41127/elementaryshr/) on 2019-05-30**:
Thanks @gvdhoorn,

The rospkg is also up to date (V 1.19)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-30**:
Did you mean to write `1.1.9`?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-30**:
Just noticed this:

> ubuntu 14.04 and ros kinetic version

Kinetic is not supported on Ubuntu 14.04; are you building things from source or is this a typo?

**Comment by [elementaryshr](https://answers.ros.org/users/41127/elementaryshr/) on 2019-05-30**:
I am extreamly sorry, I typed out both the things rather quickly.

The Ubuntu version is 16.04.6
The rospkg is also 1.1.9

I have installed it via package manager.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2019-05-31**:
Have you tried upgrading packages: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` before installing?

**Comment by [elementaryshr](https://answers.ros.org/users/41127/elementaryshr/) on 2019-05-31**:
Yes indeed. All the packages are up to date

**Comment by [Sensenzhl](https://answers.ros.org/users/91351/sensenzhl/) on 2021-12-24**:
Have you solved the problem? I meet this problem too today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved the issue by updating pip2. Apparently I had 3 pip installations pip (this should be pip2), pip2, pip3.

---

Originally posted by [elementaryshr](https://answers.ros.org/users/41127/elementaryshr/) with karma: 28 on 2019-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-03-23**:
This didn't solve it for me on one of my machines, but for completeness:
`sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip`
https://askubuntu.com/questions/712339/how-to-upgrade-pip-to-latest